# How do I change the linked page which appears at the right of a Facebook group when I have two linked pages in the group?

Tags: facebook-pages, facebook-groups

I have two linked Facebook pages in a Facebook group. Both of them appear as linked pages in the top banner, but only one appears in the right side of the group.

I want to change the one which is displayed at the right for the other Facebook linked page I have in the group.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is the answer for this. Go to group settings, then linked pages, then edit linked pages, then click the 3 dots button of the desired page, then click the option "set page" or "pin page". I'm translated the answer from a spanish speaking Facebook so the options from the menu names may vary a little.